# Most Instructive Open Source Android Projects?

Tags: android

I'm looking to compile a list of instructive open-source Android projects.

My criteria for instructiveness:

- High code quality
- Good API coverage, demonstrating how various parts of the API interact
- Continually improved, showing that the designs are in fact maintainable
- Good aesthetic quality

In other words, the apps that as *intermediate to advanced* Android developers we should be looking to for guidance, and not simply tutorials that demo a few concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I learned a lot going through the [K9 Email Client](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [NPR Android](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/)